# Menu item icons no longer display on Android Emulator

Tags: android, menu, icons, updates

As the title says, my menu items no longer have their icons in the Android emulator. I am developing with API 16 and recently downloaded an update that became available for the SDK and the ARM image. Even after removing and reinstalling the whole Android SDK, the issue persists. I know that it isn't my own code because I reverted to a known version and it also has the same issue. The same version runs on an actual device as expected. I also previously ran the app on the emulator using API 7 and the icons appear just fine. Does anyone know if this is a known issue with the recent update?

Screenshot:

[image]

Previously, the menu items all appeared in a row at the bottom with icons above the text.

Comment: Please edit your question with screenshots illustrating what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As the title says, my menu items no longer have their icons in the Android emulator.

This is the way the overflow appears on Android 4.0+, for devices and emulators with an off-screen MENU button.

> Even after removing and reinstalling the whole Android SDK, the issue persists.

It will persist on the tens of millions of Android 4.x devices as well, or at least those that have a MENU button. Devices sans MENU button will have a similar-looking drop-down menu, emanating from the ... affordance on the right side of their action bar.

> The same version runs on an actual device as expected.

That actual device is not running Android 4.x, presumably.

> Does anyone know if this is a known issue with the recent update?

If by "recent update" you mean the nearly-year-old release of Android 4.0, then yes.

Comment: When I ran the Android SDK Manager a couple of days ago, it told me that there were updates available for "Documentation for Android SDK", "SDK Platform", and "ARM EABI v7a System Image". I downloaded all of these and they now have a "3" in the "Rev." column. This is the "recent update" to which I am referring.

Comment: @Code-Guru: This has been the behavior, in Android 4.x devices and emulators, since the release of Android 4.0.

Comment: Prior to this update, the menu button on the emulator showed the non-overflow menu with icons. If I understand your question correctly, the behavior of a hard menu button changed in Android 4.x. So perhaps this behavior was incorrect in the emulator and was recently updated to reflect the behavior on an actual device?

Comment: That's strange because I've worked on this program for several months targetting API 16. This is the first time I have seen this particular behavior.

Comment: @Code-Guru: "So perhaps this behavior was incorrect in the emulator and was recently updated to reflect the behavior on an actual device?" -- I have seen this behavior on the emulator since the release on Android 4.0. What *may* be different is if you changed your `android:targetSdkVersion` -- if that had been 10 or lower, you would get the old-style options menu. Changing it to 11+ would give you the new-style overflow along with your action bar.

Comment: Well, thanks for the help! I'll just take this as expected behavior and get back to the real work...

Comment: oooo....I did start looking at the targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion attributes recently...

Comment: @Code-Guru: Yeah, that's the most likely scenario for the change in behavior that you are seeing.

Comment: Yup, removing the `<uses-sdk>` tag from my manifest file gives the behavior that I previously saw.